# Can I join multiple lists in SharePoint Query with conditions?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, caml-query

I want you guys to clarify to me if SharePoint lists can be handled as Tables in Sql? Am I allowed to use join? and conditions on that query?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes you can use CAML in SharePoint to apply conditions and even join multiple lists in SharePoint

But if you have too much relational structure than I will suggest you to use SQL Server and ASP.NET application instead.

SharePoint can't handle large data and too many relations very effectively.

[CAML Query tutorial for SharePoint](http://sharepoint-works.blogspot.com/2012/05/caml-query-tutorial-for-sharepoint.html)

[List joins and Projections](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ee539975(v=office.14).aspx)